# Ratio of moment generating function with it's derivative

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems, moment-generating-functions

> Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution function $F$. Let $\phi(t) = E[e^{t X}]$ be the moment generating function. Let $x_0 = \sup\{x : F(x) < 1\}$ be a finite quantity. Prove that $\phi(t)$ exists for all $t > 0$, and $\frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi(t)} \to x_0$ as $t \to \infty$.

The first part of this problem is very easy. Note that $e^{tX} = e^{tX}(1_{\{X > x_0\}} + 1_{\{x_0 \geq X > 0\}} + 1_{\{X \leq 0\}})$, which is bounded by $e^{tx_0}1_{\{x_0 \geq X > 0\}} + 1$, and hence the expectation is bounded by $e^{tx_0} + 1$ for all $t$.

However, for the second part,I have found a few things, but I am not able to piece then together:

- $\phi'(t) = E[Xe^{tX}]$.
- $\frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi(t)}$ is an increasing function bounded by $x_0$.

Hence, it's sufficient if I can prove that $\sup_t {\frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi(t)}} = x_0$. However, I am somewhat stuck here.

Comment: I am interested in how you proved that $\frac{\phi'(t)}{\phi(t)}$ is increasing (i.e. convexity of cumulant generating function.) Did you use Hölder's inequality or is there an easier way?

Comment: I observed that the derivative of the above quantity is the variance of the exponential tilted function, hence is always positive (or, take the derivative and apply Cauchy-Schwarz(-Bunyakovsky) inequality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is even easier: the $X\leq 0$ doesn't need to be treated as a special case; you can just use $1_{X\leq x_0}.$

For the second part, one way you could start is to consider $a<x_0$ and show that $\mathbb E[1_{X\leq a}e^{tX}]/\mathbb E[e^{tX}]\to 0.$ This is because $\mathbb E[1_{X\leq a}e^{tX}]\leq e^{at},$ whereas for any $a<b<x_0$ we have $\mathbb E[e^{tX}]\geq \mathbb P[X\geq b]e^{bt}$ which dominates $e^{at}$ for large $t.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am busy so I will get back  to you in some time.

Comment: Yes, your answer makes perfect sense. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gamma(t)=\ln(\phi(t))$ and $p_\epsilon=\mathsf{P}(X\ge x_0-\epsilon)$. $\gamma'$ is non-decreasing ($\because \gamma''\ge 0$) and bounded by $x_0$. For any $\epsilon>0$, $p_{\epsilon}>0$ and $\gamma(t)\ge t(x_0-\epsilon)+\ln(p_{\epsilon})$ so that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\gamma'(t)\ge x_0-\epsilon$.

Comment: $p_0$ could be zero.